# Why did I fall through the world and how do I fix that?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I logged into my world and fell through the world, like the blocks had no collision box. How can I fix this? And it happens every 5 min so I'm going around then it starts I'm trying to fix the block my replacing them it seems it's working but when I re log it  glitches  again

Comment: Did you actually die!?  This happens a lot when the game lags severely. I just go into creative and fly back up until it passes.

Comment: (The new minecraft versions have the same issue as the 1.7.4 as in the possible duplicate)

Comment: Are you playing on a server? Does this happen every time, or was is just once?

Comment: On my own world all the time I try creative it slows it down il try to brake the block as I fall and replace them

Comment: Oh, so this is single player?

Comment: Yeah it is btw it's not open to LAN